# AWS EB deployment pipeline script is the same for Codeschip Basic vs Pro?

Tags: codeship

Just wondering if AWS EB deployment pipelines use the same script in Codeship Basic / Pro subscriptions?

https://github.com/codeship-library/aws-utilities/blob/master/deployment/scripts/codeship_aws_eb_deploy

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ElasticBeanstalk deployment script for Codeship Basic is very similar to the script available at https://github.com/codeship/scripts/blob/master/deployments/elastic_beanstalk.sh

There are a couple differences, because of the way it is directly integrated into Codeship Basic itself. Same for the Basic/Pro versions, they are very similar, but not completely identical.

Comment: Thanks @mlocher, that is consistent with Codeship support answer.

Comment: Thats great since I work for Codeship (though I didn't answer your ticket personally) 